# Contract function has been pending for too long

Tags: tokens, gas, contract-invocation

I made this call to my smart contract using remix: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x9bcec02573db09054ac7bc00e5a7826b68ea8b0d929a6d07737ddfb1041ff887

When I try to make the call from my actual application, it just stays pending for ages: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xd64b61d3a469e10116781f8af090b690b5c9091f8ca4f1bd33bec4108fa1435a

The call from remix used 35k gas and my limit is 40k - so I believe thats fine.

The gas price for the remix call seems to have been 2.5gwei, the request from my app is using 8.9gwi (which I set after looking at this website: https://dashboards.anyblock.tools/ethereum/ethereum/ropsten/gas-metrics/

Anyone know what the problem is??

Comment: Try with more gas, 1M for example. The gas usage depends on the contract state, for example transferring a token to a new address is more expensive than transferring to an address with non-zero balance.

Comment: @Ismael all of my transactions were being held up by an old transaction that had a gas price too low (their nonces were all in sequence). I ended up having to override the old transaction which had a gas price too low,